# Elliptical Marquee Tool - Adjusting after selection Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs5, selections, marquee-tool

How do I refine/adjust my selection after?
Right now, I just randomly click in the top left hand corner
and drag until I get the desired outline, but this seems
very inefficient.

Here is an example of the circle images and one of my attempts to
select around it.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly you'd like to either move it or manipulate the selection. Moving it is as easy as staying on the marquee tool and dragging the circle where you would like it. If you need to manipulate it a bit after the fact, then you can choose "transform selection" which is located under the "Select" menu at the top. Hope this helps.

Comment: YES!  Thank you, that is exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

I've always done this a different way. To start with, try using guides on the page to mark the edges of your element, like so...

[image: Find the edges]

Now use the *Elliptical Marquee Tool* to highlight the required image:

[image: With marquee]

Answer (score 0):

With the Marquee Tool selected, you also **expand** your selection holding the **shift** key + click and drag. That would add up to your existing selection.
You can also **subtract**, holding the **alt** key + click and drag.

There's also the option of clicking inside the selection and dragging, to change its position. That was already mentioned though.

You can feather your selection, by right-clicking on the selection and select "Feather...". You should experiment with this, since your image doesn't have hard edges and if you'd like to be a little more precise.

Hope that was helpful for future projects :) cheers!